# My system won't shutdown.... I have to press the power button to shutdown

Tags: shutdown

I am using elementary OS, but sometimes my system won't shutdown: it freezes with the elementary logo without powering off. What to do?

Comment: Press ESC on shutdown and look for errors. Post them to find an answer

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file

```
sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/default/grub
```

And modify the line :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

It to obtain this line :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq acpi=force apm=power_off quiet splash"
```

Then, save, close, and back in the terminal, execute :

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now, when you will Shutdown, it should work.